# How to include dotfuscated output in my setup project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, setup-project, dotfuscator

I am using visual studio 2010.

Having a windows application and a setup project ( visual studio's setup project ), and now i want to protect my code by using the preemptive solution dotfuscator.

How can i first build my windows application, dotfuscate the output, and make my setup project include the dotfuscated output and not the orginal one?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use post build event http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4(v=vs.80).aspx
to call dotfuscator from command line (maybe you need to be registred for that , should be free).  http://www.preemptive.com/support/dotfuscator-support

Comment: Hi
I know that part, but how do i get the obfuscated .exe file in the setup project and not the original file?

Comment: 2 solution you can replace the original exe by the obfuscated one , or in your setup project take the obfuscated exe as a source (ie don't take the original project output). Maybe just put the objuscated exe in a folder next to debug , and include this location in the setup.